# CSS - Make Content infront of animated background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animated background from Codepen (link below) I cannot get my text to float in-front of the background however. I haven't included the js as I dont think it will help

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zessx/pen/ZGBMXZ

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/37568fdb9681e4c9d67d4d88fc7658ba

I have tried using z-index and using an absolute position isnt helping either.

`Index.html` Note: I have removed code that is irrelevant

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="bg"></div>

        <div class="content w3-content" style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;">
            <h1 class="font w3-jumbo w3-text-black">MOLLY URS</h1>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

`style.css`

```
.bg {
    z-index: 1;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center ellipse, #721B94 0%, #210627 100%) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #721B94 0%, #210627 100%);
    overflow: hidden;
    }

body    {
    margin: 0;
}

.content    {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I can't see your `.content` div when I view the source of the codepen.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain, I used the code from the codepen, the codepen isnt my code

Comment: No problem. Joseph Marikle has answered your question and I have added a codepen as a comment to that answer to help you understand the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553245/8085668.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed position to the text container will solve this issue.

```
<div  class="content w3-content" style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%; position : fixed">
        <h1 class="font w3-jumbo w3-text-black">MOLLY URS</h1>
    </div>
```

I have working plunker here [[link]](https://plnkr.co/edit/6CMBuJ2CteEF5FQr9Mkr?p=preview)

Comment: Just for the record, this would also work with `position:absolute`. The main issue was that the position of the element on the screen had not been specified. In this example rather than specifying the position of the `.content` element, the `.content` HTML has been moved above the `.bg` HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` should in most cases be paired with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and/or `right`.  You are missing `top:0` or similar.  You shouldn't need to change `z-index`.  `.content` comes later in the DOM, so it'll be "painted" above `#bg`.

Comment: Joseph beat me to it, so this is a codepen of what they are talking about. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRwddm. I have just added the correct positional CSS to center the text. The text was basically off the screen, because of the reasons outlined in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Place html text first, the bg last.
Attach `position: fixed;` to text container.